# remove "wrapping" array (remove parent, keep children)

Tags: php

I have a problem, i'd like to remove the containing array (key 80) but keep its children (with all the keys and structure unchanged, apart from the parent).

Can somebody help me

```
Array
(
    [80] => Array
        (
            [parent] => 0
            [lng] => en
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [98] => Array
                        (
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [54] => Array
                                        (
                                            [parent] => 98
                                            [lng] => en
                                        )

                                )

                            [parent] => 80
                            [lng] => en
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thank you,
BR

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like all you need is

```
$children = $all[80];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do:

```
$array=$array[80];
```

you preserve the children and remove the parent